# Floating point exception while upgrading via apt

Tags: pi-zero-w, apt, update

When I attempt an `apt upgrade` on my Raspberry Pi Zero W I get the following output:

```
Fetched 5,864 kB in 10s (580 kB/s)
Floating point exception
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10 returned an error code (1)
E: Failure running script /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10
```

The only way I've found around this is to modify `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20listchanges` and comment the first line.

```
DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs { "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10"; };
```

Without doing that, the upgrade fails out and does not complete.

Has anyone else run into this?